# Testing if an element is in the list or not

Tags: python

the program is supposed to ask for another input if the name input already has been entered before by checking if that name exists in the list. but the problem is the elements of the list are tuples how can a fix that?

```
from datetime import datetime
ToDoList = []
time = datetime.now()
date_format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"


def addNewItems():
    global ToDoList
    while True:
        name = input("Please enter your task name: ")
        if name in ToDoList:
            print("Task already exists! Select the options again.")
        elif name not in ToDoList:
            break
    while True:
        date = input(
            "Please enter your task completion date as yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS: ")
        date = datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
        if date < time:
            print("Time entered is in the past! Select the options again")
        elif date >= time:
            break
    task = (name, date)
    ToDoList = ToDoList.append(task)
    print("Task added successfully!")
    ToDoList.sort()
```

Comment: Use `else` instead of `elif` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 simple methods to do this.

Firstly, you can store `ToDoList` as a dictionary rather than a list of tuples, which seems appropriate for your use case as this is the kind of thing dictionaries were made for. If this you want to do this, just replace:
`ToDoList = []` with `ToDoList = {}`

and replace

```
task = (name, date)
ToDoList = ToDoList.append(task)
print("Task added successfully!")
ToDoList.sort()
```

with

```
ToDoList[name] = date
print("Task added successfully!")
ToDoList = {k:ToDoList[k] for k in sorted(ToDoList)}
```

Bear in mind that with this way, the sorting of `ToDoList` is less efficient.

If you don't want to use a dictionary, you can replace

```
if name in ToDoList:
    print("Task already exists! Select the options again.")
elif name not in ToDoList:
    break
```

with

```
if any(name == task[0] for task in ToDoList):
    print("Task already exists! Select the options again.")
else:
    break
```

or (on a similar vein):

```
if name in [task[0] for task in ToDoList]:
    print("Task already exists! Select the options again.")
else:
    break
```

The first of those 2 solutions uses the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function, which allows you to iterate through an itterable and manipulate the element at each iteration to get a `bool`. If any of those bools are `True`, the statement returns `True`.

The second solution uses [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), which allows you to reduce a for loop to one line and produce a list with it.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is in a list of tuples you can use list comprehension.

```
if name in [task[0] for task in ToDoList]:
    print('Task already exists! Select the options again.')
else:
    break
```

This loops over all the items in `ToDoList` and checks whether `name` is in the first element of the tuple.